# Am I thinking correctly about Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a bunch of BGP AS numbers from the networking world and I thought if I put them all in dictionary format I would be able to search them quickly with a user input of which AS number they were looking for and have it print out the key values to say where that AS number was in use city wise:

```
a12345  =   {'Region': 'VEND', 'AS':    '12345',    'City': 'Shanghai China'}

a56789  =   {'Region': 'VEND', 'AS':    '56789',    'City': 'Singapore'}

a98765  =   {'Region': 'EMEA', 'AS':    '98765',    'City': 'Concesio, IT'}
```

When I get the user input I get a can't call dictionary with a string if I try to concatenate the user entered 5 digit number converted to a string and adding 'a'+.

```
>>> print(test)
a12345

>>> type(test)
<class 'str'>

>>> a12345.get('AS')
'12345'

>>> test.get('AS')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Is there any way to convert user input into a different type say a dict?

I'm a true NEWBIE in Python so hopefully my question is framed in the right fashion.

Comment: where comes `test` in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `a12345` is a variable name, and `test` is a `str`. If you're going to receive input from a user and want to do lookups based on that input, you should structure your data differently.

```
data = {
    'a12345': {
        'Region': 'VEND',
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

and then you can do

```
data.get(test, {}).get('AS')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to structure your data like so:

```
a = {'12345': {'Region': 'VEND', 'City': 'Shanghai China'},
     '56789': {'Region': 'VEND', 'City': 'Singapore'},
     '98765': {'Region': 'EMEA', 'City': 'Concesio, IT'}}
```

Then to access 12345, you can use `a['12345']`.